# What is an edge router and how does it work?

Tags: networking, router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an edge server / router / device?](https://serverfault.com/questions/67484/what-is-an-edge-server-router-device)

Can someone tell me what an Edge Router is and how it works?  Examples and analogies are always welcome.

Comment: I think this is close enough to be a duplicate.  http://serverfault.com/questions/67484/what-is-an-edge-server

Comment: I don't really see enough information on that question regarding edge routers, specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An edge router is simply a router that connects the network you control to a network that you don't.  In most cases, it is the router that's connected directly to your internet connection.

This is in opposition to a core router, which is a router that routes between multiple networks that are all under your control.

An edge router is generally a lower-end router, as it tends not to do much beyond pass traffic, and generally to a circuit that has a relatively low bandwidth.  Edge routers are sometimes combined with firewalls, NATs, and VPN endpoints, but I'm not really sure you'd still call it an edge router at that point.

Comment: nice summary. +1.